# local class incompatible error

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

The following code gives me the error `InvalidClassException`    My `User` class implements `Serializable` so I'm lost. I'm trying to store `list` filled with `User` objects and then be able to read it back.

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();//list used
try {
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName, true));

    os.writeObject(userList);
    os.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

// input
try {
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
    userList = (List<User>) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You are using "append" `new FileOutputStream(fileName, true)` ... Did your file start out empty?  The file may start off with bad content from previous testing.  Delete it and retest.

Comment: Thank you that worked is there a way to avoid this in the future?

Comment: Err, yes, don't append to object output streams. However that would cause a different error. The error here is that the local class named is different from the class as it was when it was serialized, in a way that is mentioned in the error message, which you unhelpfully didn't provide.

Comment: Yes, you can avoid it in the future by not opening the `FileOutputStream` for "appending", by changing the `true` argument to `false`, or leaving it off entirely.  Since this is now working for you, I've posted this as an answer (below) which you can "accept" to __*close this question*__ by clicking the grey checkmark to the right of the answer.  I've also added some coding suggestions (try-with-resources, multi-catch) which may assist your code in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to store and later retrieve a single object (a `List<>` in your example) in a file, you do ***not*** want to ***append*** to the file each time you write to it.  Rather, you want to ***overwrite*** the file each time, with the new object.

```
// Write
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
    oos.writeObject(userList);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

// read
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
    userList = (List<User>) ois.readObject();
} catch (FileNotFoundException  | IOException | ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Notice `new FileOutputStream(fileName)` does ***not*** have the `true` argument.  Using the `true` argument indicates you want to open the file for "append".  Using `false`, or leaving the append argument off entirely, will open the file for "overwrite".

Notes:

I've also used the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement my example.  This eliminates the need for explicitly closing the streams; the streams are automatically closed for you at the end of the `try { }` block.

I've also used the [multi-catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) clause, because you are not handling the 3 exceptions any differently, so it is a bit cleaner.

Comment: Yes!!, Thank you so much i was going crazy over this.

Comment: Would this delete stored information (Users) in the file that has already been created? @AJNeufeld?

Comment: The code above writes the entire `List<User>` as one object, destroying whatever was in that file.  If you want to add / modify / remove users, you would read in the entire list (if the file exists), make the required modifications to the list, and write out the list to the file.

Comment: If you only ever want to add users to the list (never modify the user's data or remove a user), this could be done another way, using append to write new entries to the file.  You would only write the new `User` objects to the `ObjectOutputStream`, not the entire `List<User>`, and when reading, you would loop until the end of the file, reading `User` objects one at a time and adding those to an internal `List<User>`.